# PHP ErrorException creation takes a long time

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

After profiling a PHP script, I found that creating an exception appears to take a huge amount of time:

> ```
> %Time            Real      User    System Calls         secs/call  Name
> 100.0    0.00 3448.05 0.00 8.89 0.00 1.81     1  0.0000 3448.0543  main
>  64.7 2230.28 2230.28 0.02 0.02 0.00 0.00   892  2.5003    2.5003  sleep
>  35.1    0.01 1211.84 0.00 8.16 0.00 1.49  1001  0.0000    1.2106  do_process
>  34.7  986.81 1197.34 2.59 2.60 1.18 1.18  1330  0.7420    0.9003  file_get_contents
>   6.1    0.00  210.53 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.01    28  0.0000    7.5191  __lambda_func
>   6.1  210.53  210.53 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01    28  7.5191    7.5191  ErrorException->__construct
>   0.4    0.00   13.47 0.01 5.21 0.00 0.18   206  0.0000    0.0654  do_check
>   0.4   13.15   13.15 5.08 5.08 0.15 0.15   402  0.0327    0.0327  preg_replace
> ```

So that's 7.5 seconds of real (not CPU) time per `ErrorException->__construct`.  **I'm looking for ideas on how to improve this!**

Relevant code:

> ```
> set_error_handler(
>   create_function(
>     '$severity, $message, $file, $line',
>     'throw new ErrorException($message, $severity, $severity, $file, $line);'
>   )
> );
>
> $opts = array(
>   'http' => array(
>     'method'  => 'GET',
>     'timeout' => 60
>   )
> );
> $ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
> try {
>   $this->data = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
> } catch (Exception $e) {
>   # The set_error_handler call ensures that we arrive here on any type
>   # of error.
>   $this->data = '';
>   if(preg_match('/HTTP\/1.[0|1] 4[0-9][0-9] /', $e->getMessage()) == 1) {
>     return 404;
>   } else if(strpos($e->getMessage(), "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed") !== false) {
>     return 1000;
>   } else {
>     $this->message = $e->getMessage();
>     return -1;
>   }
> }
> ```

Even if there's no obvious answer, I'd like to understand what factors could influence the real time to be so large.  My understanding is that the constructor doesn't include time for the `file_get_contents` call itself or the `catch` clause, so can't really think of a good reason (other than trying to allocate a huge amount of memory) why this should be slow.

Comment: Error handling based on error message and string manipulation is not a good practice.

Comment: @Mikk suggestion of a better way is welcome, but I don't think this is causing the slowness!

Comment: After some further investigation, the problem may be with the APD profiler. I put an innocuous call in the error handler function before the `throw` (e.g. `$x=time()`) and the profiler then showed the entire 7.5 sec moving from the `ErrorException->__construct` to `time()`. First, I suspect the profiler is attributing some of the `file_get_contents` wait time to the constructor. Second, it seems that only some error types do this, i.e. in the above example it is not 28 calls at 7.5 sec each, but 8 calls at 60 sec each (== the timeout) and the remaining 20 are very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit more testing, the problem appears to be with how APD profiling measures the elapsed time.  If I put any other statement inside the error handler before `throw`, the profiler counts all the elapsed time against that, as mentioned in my comment.

Therefore, I'm convinced that the high elapsed time is because the profiler actually includes elapsed time from `file_get_contents`.

I tried using XHProf instead, and this seems to give more correct results.  At least, it shows the `ErrorException->__construct` as taking only minimal elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an oldschool lambda function created with a call to `create_function()`. Is there a reason for this? Because the way that function operates is slow. You pass it a STRING with the code of the function, but that string has to be evaluated during runtime. There is no way the opcode cache could cache that code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. No particular reason. I tried using `set_error_handler("exception_error_handler")` (with function `exception_error_handler` appropriately defined) and didn't notice a huge difference. Since I had tested that less thoroughly than the code I posted in the question, I went with that. Following your answer I'll run longer tests without using create_function(). BTW, this script runs for a long time in the background so opcode caching isn't such a big deal to me, but the point is well-taken!